# ContinuationStateStack empty warning when using WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I don't know the reason, but suddenly i got warnings when using WSO2 ESB 4.9.0 APIs like this:

> TID: [-1234] [] [2016-08-22 11:26:31,951]  WARN
>   {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment} - 
>   ContinuationStateStack empty. No ContinuationState to mediate the
>   response  {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment}

I am using a simple call mediator in my service like this:

```
<call>
  <endpoint>
     <http method="GET"
           uri-template="https://test.com/{uri.var.test}"/>
  </endpoint>
</call>
```

What causes this? Because my APIs don't return anything (it gives connection timeout)

> Connection time out after request is read: http-incoming-2047

Comment: What do you have after `call` mediator? Better if you can post entire synapse config.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the following property if the API Call is not expecting a response.

```
<property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the API call is expecting response.

Comment: But seems your back-end connection is timing out. Can you directly invoke https://test.com/test BE without a timeout?